# Rails with PostgreSQL reconnecting multiple times per request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, postgresql, pg

I recently encountered a problem where Rails is dropping connections to my PostgreSQL causing multiple reconnects per request, significantly slowing down requests. I am currently running everything local on Mac OS X with the following environment:

- Mac OS X 10.8 (Mountain Lion)
- Pow
- NginX (ssl unwrapping - same app reconnect behavior even without this enabled)
- PostgreSQL 9.2.2 via Homebrew
- Rails 3.2.11

Here is my `database.yml`: *(database and username redacted)*

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: <database>
  pool: 5
  username: <user>
  password:
```

This is the output from `development.log` during a typical request: *(specific models and renders redacted)*

```
Connecting to database specified by database.yml


Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-05 12:25:38 -0800
Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
  ... <app performs model loads and render calls>
Completed 200 OK in 314ms (Views: 196.0ms | ActiveRecord: 60.9ms)
Connecting to database specified by database.yml
Connecting to database specified by database.yml
```

I also enabled statement logging in Postgres to get better insight into what exactly was happening on the database side during a given request. Here is the output from `postgresql-<date>.log`: *(queries specific to my app redacted)*

```
LOG:  connection received: host=[local]
LOG:  connection authorized: user=<user> database=<database>
LOG:  statement: set client_encoding to 'UTF8'
LOG:  statement: set client_encoding to 'unicode'
LOG:  statement: SHOW client_min_messages
LOG:  statement: SET client_min_messages TO 'panic'
LOG:  statement: SET standard_conforming_strings = on
LOG:  statement: SET client_min_messages TO 'notice'
LOG:  statement: SET time zone 'UTC'
LOG:  statement: SHOW TIME ZONE
LOG:  statement: SELECT 1
LOG:  statement: SELECT 1
    ... <app makes queries for request>
LOG:  disconnection: session time: 0:00:01.346 user=<user> database=<database> host=[local]
LOG:  connection received: host=[local]
LOG:  connection authorized: user=<user> database=<database>
LOG:  statement: set client_encoding to 'UTF8'
LOG:  statement: set client_encoding to 'unicode'
LOG:  statement: SHOW client_min_messages
LOG:  statement: SET client_min_messages TO 'panic'
LOG:  statement: SET standard_conforming_strings = on
LOG:  statement: SET client_min_messages TO 'notice'
LOG:  statement: SET time zone 'UTC'
LOG:  statement: SHOW TIME ZONE
LOG:  statement: SELECT 1
LOG:  connection received: host=[local]
LOG:  connection authorized: user=<user> database=<database>
LOG:  statement: set client_encoding to 'UTF8'
LOG:  statement: set client_encoding to 'unicode'
LOG:  statement: SHOW client_min_messages
LOG:  statement: SET client_min_messages TO 'panic'
LOG:  statement: SET standard_conforming_strings = on
LOG:  statement: SET client_min_messages TO 'notice'
LOG:  statement: SET time zone 'UTC'
LOG:  statement: SHOW TIME ZONE
LOG:  statement: SELECT 1
LOG:  statement: SELECT 1
LOG:  statement: SELECT 1
LOG:  disconnection: session time: 0:00:00.750 user=<user> database=<database> host=[local]
LOG:  disconnection: session time: 0:00:00.733 user=<user> database=<database> host=[local]
```

I'm happy to update with relevant configs or log outputs for command calls. Also, why all the `SELECT 1` calls? What is their purpose?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to upgrade PostgreSQL to a newer version. I just upgraded to `9.2.4` from `9.2.2` as used in the original question and the problem went away entirely, with expected performance characteristics returning to my development application.